# More efficient way of writing this function

Tags: jquery

Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

I try to archive a terser code. Something like:

value: { Angebotsmappen, Angebotsordner, Abheftmappen, Außendienstmappen ...  },

```
$(function(){
  var tags = [
    { value: 'Angebotsmappen' },
    { value: 'Angebotsordner' },
    { value: 'Abheftmappen' },
    { value: 'Außendienstmappen' },
    { value: 'Firmenmappen' },
    { value: 'Flipcharts' },
    { value: 'Grafikmappen' },
    { value: 'Geschenkschachteln' },
    { value: 'Hotelmappen' },
    { value: 'Infomappen' },
    { value: 'Konferenzmappen' },
    { value: 'Klemmbretter' },
    { value: 'Klemmmappen' }
  ];



  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: tags,
    width: "auto",
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    document.location.href = "/search?q=" + $(this).val()
    }
  });
```

});

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Given that the function has no purpose what are you looking to optimise?

Comment: I would redirect you to the codereview stack exchange. It's a great place to get the kind of feedback you seem to be looking for.

Comment: What do you mean more efficient? Faster runtime? Terser code? Minimizing File Size? Catching the moon?

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ['Angebotsmappen', 'Angebotsordner', 'Abheftmappen', 'Außendienstmappen']; //until whatever
var tags = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    tags.push({'value': tags[i]});
}
```

Just create an array of names, and use a loop to create a key/value pair.

If you're comfortable with functional programming `(maps)`, this is even shorter:

```
 ['Angebotsmappen', 
'Angebotsordner', 
'Abheftmappen', 
'Außendienstmappen'].map(function(i){return {value: i}});
```

Comment: Not sure using two variables instead of one and using a loop is really more efficient...

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf It's definitely terser (which OP wanted)

Comment: Post was edited, OP didn't talk about terser in original post :)